# How to return an error in a stored procedure and insert into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I don't know that much about SQL Server but essentially what I have here is a stored procedure that should insert parameters (id (primary key) and Test data) into a test table, dbo.test

If it fails to add them it should instead add to dbo.Error_Log with the id, test data AND Error information.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
    @Id int = 0, 
    @Test_column nvarchar(10) = 0
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AdventureWorks2012.dbo.Error_Log ([Id], [Data], [Error_description])
        SELECT  @Id,
                @Test_column,
                @@ERROR
        END
        ELSE
    INSERT INTO AdventureWorks2012.dbo.Test ([Id], [Test_column])
    SELECT  @Id, 
            @Test_column
END
```

And I'm executing it like this:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[uspTester]
        @Id = 1,
        @Test_column = N'data123'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO


SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2012.dbo.Test
SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2012.dbo.Error_Log
```

It returns a populated dbo.Test, an empty dbo.Error_Log and a return value of -4 for some reason

Error is:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure uspTester, Line 21
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Test__3214EC0775996C4D'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Test'. The duplicate key
>   value is (1). The statement has been terminated.

I need to have that error output into dbo.Error_Log and not just stop the operation completely.

Comment: Look into TRY/CATCH it is the best way to deal with exceptions in t-sql.

Comment: for one thing, you're checking for an error before you attempt the insert that causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @@ERROR variable "returns the error number for the last Transact-SQL statement executed" i.e. you need to check the @@ERROR after you attempt the insert. Something like this:

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


INSERT INTO AdventureWorks2012.dbo.Test ([Id], [Test_column])
SELECT  @Id, 
        @Test_column

IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AdventureWorks2012.dbo.Error_Log ([Id], [Data], [Error_description])
    SELECT  @Id,
            @Test_column,
            @@ERROR
    END
END
```

Note: If you want the error message instead of the number you are going to have make use of the ERROR_MESSAGE() function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx